# How to disable the 'To' field in an In-App email using MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: ios

I have an app, the feedback of which I want the customers to send to my email address. So, I want the customer to only send me the feedback. Hence I want to lock the email 'To' field. Is this possible? I am using the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No — the API is real minimal.

Just default it to you (`setToRecipients:`).

Comment: Ya, I have the setToRecipients set to be my address, but it is enabled and someone can still delete my address and put someone else's address. Not that, thats an issue, but just to look more professional, I would like my address to show up(which it does) and be disabled so that people cannot delete it/add more address. It is not hard and fast, that this is how it needs to be. Its just that it popped up in my mind and hence I thot of implementing it, if possible. Thanks for the reply tho!