# How to set UserInteractionEnabled to false for recepients in MFMailComposeViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposer

I am using MFMailComposeViewController to send feedback from my app.

```
func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {

    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()

    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property
    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["info@myCompany.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Subject")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Body", isHTML: false)

    return mailComposerVC
}
```

In this, I don't want the user to edit the To address. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible. This small API that doesn't allow to do it.

I found some old references here in StackOverflow talking about it too:

[How to disable the 'To' field in an In-App email using MFMailComposeViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160346/how-to-disable-the-to-field-in-an-in-app-email-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroll)

[How to customize MFMailComposeViewController so that i can make the "to" field as non-editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049270/how-to-customize-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-so-that-i-can-make-the-to-field-a)

Comment: Is there any other third party module to achieve it?

Comment: I don´t know exatctly, but you could try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881751/alternative-to-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I hope it can help you.